# How can I call a javascript/typescript constructor by passing an object as parameter?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, constructor, parameter-passing

how should I write my constructor if I am calling it using the following code

```
const person = new Person({
    name,
    gender
})
```

where both name and genders are string

Update:

This is what I have got in typescript:

```
interface Details {
  name: string;
  gender: string;
}

class Person {
  name: string;
  gender: string;
  constructor({ name, gender }: Details) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
  }
}
const person = new Person({
  name: "John",
  gender: "male",
});

console.log(person);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Working Code !!***

in **JavaScript**

```js
class Person {
  constructor({name, gender}) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
  }
}
const name = 'John';
const gender = 'male';
const person = new Person({
  name,
  gender
});
console.log(person);
```

in **TypeScript**

```js
interface Details {
  name: string;
  gender: string;
}

class Person implements Details {
  constructor({ name, gender }: Details) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
  }
}
const name = 'John';
const gender = 'male';
const person = new Person({
  name,
  gender
});

console.log(person);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @solanki... I tried to implement your code in Typescript and this is what I got-
```
interface Details {
  name: string;
  gender: string;
}

class Person {
  name: string;
  gender: string;
  constructor({ name, gender }: Details) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
  }
}

//   const nam = 'John';
//   const gender = 'male';

const person = new Person({
  name: "John",
  gender: "male",
});

console.log(person);
```
Wondering if you know this is the right way?